# Method for generating numerical values from a URL

Tags: url, ascii

In the 90s there was a toy called Barcode Battler. It scanned barcodes, and from the values generated an RPG like monster with various stats such as hit points, attack power, magic power, etc. Could there be a way to do a similar thing with a URL? From just an ordinary URL, generate stats like that. I was thinking of maybe taking the ASCII values of various characters in the URL and using them, but this seems too predictable and obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Take the MD5 sum of the ASCII encoding of the URL? Incredibly easy to do on most platforms. That would give you 128 bits to come up with the stats from. If you want more, use a longer hash algorithm.

(I can't remember the details about what's allowed in a URL - if non-ASCII is allowed, you could use UTF-8 instead.)